# HPE MicroServer problem with disks on Proxmox Server (Debian)

Tags: linux, debian, hard-disk, sata, proxmox

I have a problem with disks on HPE MicroServer gen10 plus.

My server has 4 1TB HDD disks and 1 SSD NVMe on PCIE for OS. OS is Proxmox Virtual Environment 6.2-4.
I do not have any problems with this SSD disk, but Debian is reporting problems with all HDDs (randomly).

First of all - this is definitely not a problem with physical disk condition. SMART isn't reporting any real problems, I have checked all HDD disks with badblock command on pve. I also have checked this disks with GSmartControl on the same machine using HirensBoot (portable Windows) - long tests on all disks, no problems reported.

I was looking for similar problem on Internet and I have found this topic https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/550559 but none of this helped me.
I tried to use this parameters in grub config /etc/default/grub
**GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet libata.force=noncq,3.0G idex=noprobe combined_mode=libata"**
in many combinations, none of this work, I am only getting different errors.

I know that HPE do not support Debian platforms, but I believe this can be fix using special config.
Before booting PVE this time, I formatted all HDDs on HirensBoot (diskpart -> clean -> convert gpt), after booting pve, I have created anew ZFS raidz storage so you may notice errors about missing storage.

```
[ 5738.090686] ata3.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
[ 5738.090707] ata3.00: cmd 61/60:b8:98:0f:bf/01:00:14:00:00/40 tag 23 ncq dma 180224 out
                        res 50/00:58:00:12:bf/00:00:14:00:00/40 Emask 0x50 (ATA bus error)
[ 5738.090757] ata3.00: status: { DRDY }
[ 5738.090771] ata3.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
[ 5738.090792] ata3.00: cmd 61/58:f8:a8:11:bf/00:00:14:00:00/40 tag 31 ncq dma 45056 out
                        res 50/00:58:00:12:bf/00:00:14:00:00/40 Emask 0x50 (ATA bus error)
[ 5738.090848] ata3.00: status: { DRDY }
[ 5738.090863] ata3: hard resetting link
[ 5738.364263] ata1: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[ 5738.365429] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/100
[ 5738.404235] ata3: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[ 5738.406149] ata3.00: configured for UDMA/133
[ 5738.406168] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 5738.406170] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 Sense Key : Illegal Request [current]
[ 5738.406173] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 Add. Sense: Unaligned write command
[ 5738.406176] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 14 bf 12 00 00 00 58 00
[ 5738.406179] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 348066304 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x700 phys_seg 11 prio class 0
[ 5738.406238] zio pool=local-storage vdev=/dev/sdc1 error=5 type=2 offset=178208899072 size=45056 flags=180880
[ 5738.406258] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#13 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 5738.406260] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#13 Sense Key : Illegal Request [current]
[ 5738.406260] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#13 Add. Sense: Unaligned write command
[ 5738.406261] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#13 CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 14 bf 03 38 00 07 e8 00
[ 5738.406262] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 348062520 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x700 phys_seg 18 prio class 0
[ 5738.406705] zio pool=local-storage vdev=/dev/sdc1 error=5 type=2 offset=178206961664 size=1036288 flags=40080c80
[ 5738.406711] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#18 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 5738.406712] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#18 Sense Key : Illegal Request [current]
[ 5738.406713] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#18 Add. Sense: Unaligned write command
[ 5738.406714] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#18 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 06 8e bb e0 00 01 00 00
[ 5738.406715] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 110017504 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 20 prio class 0
```

dmesg - full https://pastebin.com/raw/wxpprxSb

lspci https://pastebin.com/raw/R0dmCUmn

syslog https://pastebin.com/raw/ywkgPRy8

udevadm info sda https://pastebin.com/raw/JT2cUjtC

udevadm info sdb https://pastebin.com/raw/Lk5rSaCL

udevadm info sdc https://pastebin.com/raw/gzfKQ6XK

udevadm info sdd https://pastebin.com/raw/7M2gAcFx

Do you have any ideas what can I do to fix this problem? Maybe you faced similar problem on HPE MicroServer platform?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Same errors [here](https://github.com/openzfs/zfs/issues/10094), have a look at [this](https://github.com/openzfs/zfs/issues/10094#issuecomment-623603031). Otherwise I have no clue...

Answer (score 1):

Thank's Freddy, after reading what you have send, I start to think that this problem can possibly be caused by zfs itself.
So I set up new grub config, destroy zfs zpool and created usual software raid10 on linux (mdadm) formatted to ext4

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet libata.force=3.0G,noncq"
```

Now I am reading and writing data to all disks for around 2 hours.

```
screen -S sda -dm bash -c 'dd if=/dev/sda | pv -W | dd of=/dev/null; exec bash'
screen -S sdb -dm bash -c 'dd if=/dev/sdb | pv -W | dd of=/dev/null; exec bash'
screen -S sdc -dm bash -c 'dd if=/dev/sdc | pv -W | dd of=/dev/null; exec bash'
screen -S sdd -dm bash -c 'dd if=/dev/sdd | pv -W | dd of=/dev/null; exec bash'
screen -S write -dm bash -c 'dd if=/dev/urandom bs=1M count=512000 | pv -W | dd of=/mnt/raid10/file.img; exec bash'
```

...no errors so far.

Before that, I have tried to change grub settings... again

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet libata.force=noncq,1.5G"
```

basically changing sata speed to 1.5G.
Doing the same tests on zfs pool, after few hours everything was fine, but eventually errors shows up.

I am gonna wait few more hours on mdadm raid. If no errors shows up, I will change grub setting to default and see what happens.

**Update #1**

So after few hours of tests, mdadm raid10, using this grub configs:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet libata.force=noncq"
```

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet libata.force=3.0G,noncq"
```

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet"
```

errors shows up.
I ended up with this grub config:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet libata.force=noncq"
```

and this is my dmesg:

```
[ 3231.709000] input: iLO Virtual Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/0000:01:00.4/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/0003:03F0:7029.0003/input/input4
[ 3231.767175] hid-generic 0003:03F0:7029.0003: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [iLO Virtual Keyboard] on usb-0000:01:00.4-1/input0
[ 3231.769259] input: iLO Virtual Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/0000:01:00.4/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.1/0003:03F0:7029.0004/input/input5
[ 3231.769677] hid-generic 0003:03F0:7029.0004: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.10 Mouse [iLO Virtual Keyboard] on usb-0000:01:00.4-1/input1
[ 4107.717512] ata1: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[ 4107.718594] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/100
[ 4108.185395] ata2: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[ 4108.188213] ata2.00: configured for UDMA/133
[ 4109.021399] ata3: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[ 4109.022849] ata3.00: configured for UDMA/133
[ 4293.665441] ata1: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[ 4293.666628] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/100
[ 4294.169462] ata2: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[ 4294.173118] ata2.00: configured for UDMA/133
[ 4295.129346] ata3: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[ 4295.130836] ata3.00: configured for UDMA/133
[ 4665.501550] ata1: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[ 4665.502715] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/100
[ 4666.005438] ata2: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[ 4666.008166] ata2.00: configured for UDMA/133
[ 4666.773195] ata3: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[ 4666.774982] ata3.00: configured for UDMA/133
[ 4789.721461] ata1: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[ 4789.722774] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/100
[ 4790.189353] ata2: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[ 4790.192357] ata2.00: configured for UDMA/133
[ 4790.989337] ata3: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[ 4790.991053] ata3.00: configured for UDMA/133
[ 5030.296544] usb 1-1: USB disconnect, device number 4
[ 5180.814571] perf: interrupt took too long (4058 > 4018), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 49250
[ 5345.915022] ata1: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[ 5345.916494] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/100
[ 5346.421367] ata2: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[ 5346.424985] ata2.00: configured for UDMA/133
[ 5347.245534] ata3: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[ 5347.246963] ata3.00: configured for UDMA/133
[ 5517.418919] ata2.00: exception Emask 0x50 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x280900 action 0x6 frozen
[ 5517.418942] ata2.00: irq_stat 0x08000000, interface fatal error
[ 5517.418954] ata2: SError: { UnrecovData HostInt 10B8B BadCRC }
[ 5517.418965] ata2.00: failed command: READ DMA EXT
[ 5517.418975] ata2.00: cmd 25/00:00:00:ec:0e/00:04:03:00:00/e0 tag 0 dma 524288 in
                        res 50/00:00:ff:e3:9c/00:00:1e:00:00/e0 Emask 0x50 (ATA bus error)
[ 5517.419002] ata2.00: status: { DRDY }
[ 5517.419011] ata2: hard resetting link
[ 5517.733393] ata2: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[ 5517.736361] ata2.00: configured for UDMA/133
[ 5517.736369] ata2: EH complete
[ 5532.113208] ata1: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[ 5532.114304] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/100
[ 5533.177467] ata3: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[ 5533.179138] ata3.00: configured for UDMA/133
[ 5903.173369] ata2: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[ 5903.176687] ata2.00: configured for UDMA/133
[ 5904.069616] ata3: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[ 5904.071043] ata3.00: configured for UDMA/133
[ 5904.657936] ata4: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
[ 5904.660545] ata4.00: configured for UDMA/133
[ 5965.681432] ata1: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[ 5965.682551] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/100
[ 5966.173476] ata2: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[ 5966.177228] ata2.00: configured for UDMA/133
[ 5966.945412] ata3: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[ 5966.947205] ata3.00: configured for UDMA/133
[ 6151.601575] ata1: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[ 6151.602929] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/100
[ 6152.121462] ata2: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[ 6152.125192] ata2.00: configured for UDMA/133
[ 6153.005403] ata3: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[ 6153.006854] ata3.00: configured for UDMA/133
[ 6214.265397] ata1: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[ 6214.266471] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/100
[ 6214.745511] ata2: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[ 6214.748830] ata2.00: configured for UDMA/133
[ 6215.505429] ata3: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[ 6215.507265] ata3.00: configured for UDMA/133
[ 6216.021484] ata4: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
[ 6216.023955] ata4.00: configured for UDMA/133
[ 6675.214978] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 5 using ehci-pci
[ 6675.250620] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=03f0, idProduct=7029, bcdDevice= 0.02
[ 6675.250622] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 6675.250623] usb 1-1: Product: Virtual Keyboard
[ 6675.250624] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: iLO
[ 6675.254550] input: iLO Virtual Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/0000:01:00.4/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/0003:03F0:7029.0005/input/input6
[ 6675.311600] hid-generic 0003:03F0:7029.0005: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [iLO Virtual Keyboard] on usb-0000:01:00.4-1/input0
[ 6675.313696] input: iLO Virtual Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/0000:01:00.4/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.1/0003:03F0:7029.0006/input/input7
[ 6675.313930] hid-generic 0003:03F0:7029.0006: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.10 Mouse [iLO Virtual Keyboard] on usb-0000:01:00.4-1/input1
[ 6709.049477] ata1: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[ 6709.050576] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/100
[ 6709.525374] ata2: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[ 6709.528939] ata2.00: configured for UDMA/133
[ 6710.433593] ata3: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[ 6710.435256] ata3.00: configured for UDMA/133
[ 6711.077423] ata4: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
[ 6711.079963] ata4.00: configured for UDMA/133
[ 6957.177442] ata1: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[ 6957.178442] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/100
[ 6957.653547] ata2: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[ 6957.657158] ata2.00: configured for UDMA/133
[ 6958.489453] ata3: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[ 6958.491129] ata3.00: configured for UDMA/133
[ 6986.072824] usb 1-1: USB disconnect, device number 5
[ 7019.855039] ata1: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[ 7019.856571] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/100
[ 7020.317785] ata2: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[ 7020.321061] ata2.00: configured for UDMA/133
[ 7021.083097] ata3: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[ 7021.085091] ata3.00: configured for UDMA/133
[ 7021.626752] ata4: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
[ 7021.629564] ata4.00: configured for UDMA/133
[ 7391.081550] ata1: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[ 7391.082624] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/100
[ 7391.569417] ata2: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[ 7391.572301] ata2.00: configured for UDMA/133
[ 7392.421456] ata3: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[ 7392.422873] ata3.00: configured for UDMA/133
[ 7393.017456] ata4: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
[ 7393.019883] ata4.00: configured for UDMA/133
[ 7947.997582] ata1: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[ 7947.998772] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/100
[ 7948.481544] ata2: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[ 7948.485157] ata2.00: configured for UDMA/133
[ 7949.381570] ata3: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[ 7949.383025] ata3.00: configured for UDMA/133
[ 8560.283066] perf: interrupt took too long (5099 > 5072), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 39000
[ 8566.133457] ata1: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[ 8566.134721] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/100
[ 8566.637425] ata2: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[ 8566.641073] ata2.00: configured for UDMA/133
[ 8567.489515] ata3: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[ 8567.491172] ata3.00: configured for UDMA/133
[ 8875.549469] ata1: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[ 8875.550660] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/100
[ 8876.077634] ata2: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[ 8876.080517] ata2.00: configured for UDMA/133
[ 8876.925620] ata3: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[ 8876.927076] ata3.00: configured for UDMA/133
[ 9679.021591] ata1: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[ 9679.022598] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/100
[ 9679.545550] ata2: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[ 9679.548513] ata2.00: configured for UDMA/133
[ 9680.417523] ata3: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[ 9680.419061] ata3.00: configured for UDMA/133
[ 9865.433600] ata1: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[ 9865.434803] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/100
[ 9865.909354] ata2: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[ 9865.912115] ata2.00: configured for UDMA/133
[ 9866.721578] ata3: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[ 9866.723283] ata3.00: configured for UDMA/133
[ 9928.021372] ata1: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[ 9928.022437] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/100
[ 9928.553543] ata2: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[ 9928.556255] ata2.00: configured for UDMA/133
[ 9929.437660] ata3: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[ 9929.439350] ata3.00: configured for UDMA/133
[10052.361464] ata1: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[10052.362585] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/100
[10052.901541] ata2: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[10052.905265] ata2.00: configured for UDMA/133
[10053.777668] ata3: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[10053.779073] ata3.00: configured for UDMA/133
[10682.247076] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 6 using ehci-pci
[10682.286817] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=03f0, idProduct=7029, bcdDevice= 0.02
[10682.286825] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[10682.286831] usb 1-1: Product: Virtual Keyboard
[10682.286836] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: iLO
[10682.295462] input: iLO Virtual Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/0000:01:00.4/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/0003:03F0:7029.0007/input/input8
[10682.355449] hid-generic 0003:03F0:7029.0007: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [iLO Virtual Keyboard] on usb-0000:01:00.4-1/input0
[10682.365306] input: iLO Virtual Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/0000:01:00.4/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.1/0003:03F0:7029.0008/input/input9
[10682.366419] hid-generic 0003:03F0:7029.0008: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.10 Mouse [iLO Virtual Keyboard] on usb-0000:01:00.4-1/input1
[11657.773671] ata1: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[11657.774961] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/100
[11658.269690] ata2: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[11658.272546] ata2.00: configured for UDMA/133
[11659.033640] ata3: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[11659.035321] ata3.00: configured for UDMA/133
[11667.803148] ata1.00: exception Emask 0x50 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x280900 action 0x6 frozen
[11667.803172] ata1.00: irq_stat 0x08000000, interface fatal error
[11667.803189] ata1: SError: { UnrecovData HostInt 10B8B BadCRC }
[11667.803208] ata1.00: failed command: READ DMA EXT
[11667.803224] ata1.00: cmd 25/00:00:00:1e:fe/00:0a:22:00:00/e0 tag 12 dma 1310720 in
                        res 50/00:00:00:1e:fe/00:00:22:00:00/e0 Emask 0x50 (ATA bus error)
[11667.803253] ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
[11667.803264] ata1: hard resetting link
[11667.803290] ata2.00: exception Emask 0x50 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x280900 action 0x6 frozen
[11667.804705] ata2.00: irq_stat 0x08000000, interface fatal error
[11667.805766] ata2: SError: { UnrecovData HostInt 10B8B BadCRC }
[11667.807202] ata2.00: failed command: READ DMA EXT
[11667.807270] ata2.00: cmd 25/00:00:00:f6:fd/00:0a:22:00:00/e0 tag 17 dma 1310720 in
                        res 50/00:00:ff:f5:fd/00:00:22:00:00/e0 Emask 0x50 (ATA bus error)
[11667.807394] ata2.00: status: { DRDY }
[11667.807757] ata2: hard resetting link
[11668.121448] ata1: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[11668.121502] ata2: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[11668.122598] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/100
[11668.122640] ata1: EH complete
[11668.124957] ata2.00: configured for UDMA/133
[11668.124965] ata2: EH complete
[11721.044568] ata3: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[11721.046341] ata3.00: configured for UDMA/133
```

I want to try one more time with:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet libata.force=3.0G,noncq"
```

on raid10 and leave tests for night.

Can you please tell me what this errors from dmesg exactly means?

**Update #2**

I have figured it out!

I have tried changing disks again and one of them seems to be not fully functional. One disk was causing errors on all disks- Linux was reporting multiple errors across multiple drives. The bad drive is: WD Blue 1T WD10EZEX.
Now, I have a different disk and everything seems to be working fine, including ZFS. I have already written and read hundreds of gigabytes without single error.

Comment: Looks like an error on the bus, bad checksum/response while reading data or something like that. This could also be a simple cabling issue or power problem. I would try the following things first: update firmware if available, replace cables with new quality SATA3 cables and try a different power supply if available.

Comment: The firmware is updated to the latest version (debian and uefi) and the cables are factory and somehow integrated into the server chassis, it is also a 4sata to hba cable. I doubt it's a cable problem, but I checked it before, everything seems fine.